# TypeError: server.listeners is not a function

Tags: socket.io

while using socket.io in a project I am building, I am getting an error -->

`TypeError: server.listeners is not a function at Server.attach .........`

I am a new programmer and don't have enough grasp of the concepts. Can someone help me realize the error?

This is the full error:

```
TypeError: server.listeners is not a function
    at Server.attach (C:\Users\neera\OneDrive\Desktop\CNMajorProjectBackend\codeial\node_modules\engine.io\build\server.js:577:34)   
    at attach (C:\Users\neera\OneDrive\Desktop\CNMajorProjectBackend\codeial\node_modules\engine.io\build\engine.io.js:53:12)        
    at Server.initEngine (C:\Users\neera\OneDrive\Desktop\CNMajorProjectBackend\codeial\node_modules\socket.io\dist\index.js:289:43) 
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\neera\OneDrive\Desktop\CNMajorProjectBackend\codeial\config\chat_sockets.js:27:16)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Socket.emitUntyped (C:\Users\neera\OneDrive\Desktop\CNMajorProjectBackend\codeial\node_modules\socket.io\dist\typed-events.js:69:22)
    at C:\Users\neera\OneDrive\Desktop\CNMajorProjectBackend\codeial\node_modules\socket.io\dist\socket.js:703:39
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11)
```

Comment: `new programmer` and as such new to getting helpful insights into programming problems. Well, you managed one step more than just stating you *do* have a problem: you quoted an error report in useful detail. The next step would be to present a well-chosen snippet of the source code (around&preceding server.js line 577): heed [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)